# For a given set of data, how can I check if the input has the whole group of data?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate

Translation with an example:
For a given set of movies, how can I get its category and tell if we got the full set as input or not?

```sql
        -------------------------
        | CATEGORY   | MOVIE    |
        -------------------------
        | Fantasy    | Hobbit   |
        | Fantasy    | Hellboy  |
        | Romance    | Twilight |
        | Mystery    | Memento  |
        | Mystery    | Get Out  |
```

For example, if I pass in `Hobbit, Hellboy` as input, I should get back

```sql
        -------------------------------------------
        | CATEGORY | MOVIES          | HASFULLSET |
        -------------------------------------------
        | Fantasy  | Hobbit, Hellboy | 1          |
```

If I pass in `Hobbit, Twilight` as input, I should get back

```sql
        -------------------------------------
        | CATEGORY | MOVIES    | HASFULLSET |
        -------------------------------------
        | Fantasy  | Hobbit    | 0          |
        | Romance  | Twilight  | 1          |
```

I can't get beyond this without using a subquery.

```sql
SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS GRP_COUNT 
FROM movie
WHERE Movies IN (@movies)
GROUP BY Category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
SET @movies = 'Hobbit,Hellboy';
select category,
       group_concat(case when find_in_set(Movie,@movies) then movie end) AS movies,
           case when
             count(*) = sum(case when find_in_set(Movie,@movies) then 1 else 0 end)
           then 1 else 0 end FullSet
from tbl
group by category
having movies != '';
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3sLwweZxPPFXKmFznPMNui/1)

Comment: This won't work with a variable as in OPs question because `IN` won't work with a string which is a comma separated list. You need to use `FIND_IN_SET(Movie, @movies)` instead.

Comment: @Nick Didn't know about that function! Thank you very much, very useful.

Comment: I updated your query and demo to use a variable, and also produce results as in OPs question. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3sLwweZxPPFXKmFznPMNui/1

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:** So, I misread the question and posted the wrong answer previously. But don't worry, I've make amendment to the query I've posted earlier. As far as 'without using sub-query', I can't think a way yet ;P

```
SELECT m.Category, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(movie) AS Movie,
       IF(COUNT(m.movie)=fullset, 1,0) AS HASFULLSET
    FROM movie m
        LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT category,COUNT(*) AS fullset FROM movie GROUP BY category) fs
         ON m.category=fs.category
     WHERE Movie IN ('Hobbit', 'Twilight')
GROUP BY m.Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query has a couple tricky parts:

- Comparing the matches in your list to the total for the category.
- Selecting only the categories that match.

You can address these using conditional aggregation.  That is, filter in the aggregation functions rather than in the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT Category,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN m.movie IN ( . . . ) THEN m.movie END) as movies,
       ( COUNT(*) = SUM(m.movie IN ( . . . ) ) as has_full_set
FROM movies m
GROUP BY Category
HAVING SUM( m.movie IN ( . . . ) ) > 0;
```

The `HAVING` returns only categories that have a matching movie.

If you only want to list the input movies once, you can use a subquery:

```
select category,
       group_concat(case when has_movie then movie end) as movies,
       ( count(*) = sum(has_movie) ) as has_full_set
from (select m.*,
             (m.movie in ( . . . )) as has_movie
      from m
     ) m
group by category
having sum(has_movie) > 0;
```